# Cannot scrape website using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Trying to scrape off some data from `footlocker.com` for an academic project but I get an error when I try to open the page using Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/rushabhnahar/Downloads/chromedriver")

driver.get("https://www.footlocker.com/adidas-Originals/Shoes/_-_/N- 
zrZrj?cm_REF=Shoes&crumbs=991")
```

It opens up the browser and the respective page but gives an error saying 'We are sorry'.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: url should be similar to this : `https://www.footlocker.com/product/adidas-originals-nmd-r1--mens/G27916.html` issue with url code is fine

Comment: @RoshanBagdiya When I use the url you provided, it opens up the page and continues to keep loading. Does not open the page with all its content.

Comment: can you please share error you are getting @Rushabh